Click Log to view C# Source Code in VS Code
With NodeJS in VSCode all console.log logs have a clickable link which takes you to the source code line where the log was generated:

How can we achieve the same result with csharp?

The goal should be that each log entry is clickable to take one to the source code location.

I did some googling and didnt find a standard solution for that. Since I do not know how familiar you are with C#, I created the following example to demonstrate the wanted behaviour.
First you want to use the ILoggerFactory to implement a custom logging instance.
Then we will need a custom Log extension method which outputs the filepath including the filenumber. Visual Studio Code will then catch the link making it clickable.
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions;

using ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
        {
            builder.AddConsole(options =>
            {
                options.FormatterName = "lineLogger";
            })
            .AddConsoleFormatter<CustomFormatter, ConsoleFormatterOptions>();
        });

var _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();
_logger.LogWithLocation("Test Log");

public class CustomFormatter : ConsoleFormatter
{
    public CustomFormatter() : base("lineLogger") { }
    public override void Write<TState>(in LogEntry<TState> logEntry, IExternalScopeProvider scopeProvider, TextWriter textWriter)
    {
        textWriter.WriteLine($"{logEntry.Formatter(logEntry.State, logEntry.Exception)}");
    }
}
public static class LoggerExtensions
{
    public static void LogWithLocation(this ILogger logger, string message, [CallerFilePath] string filePath = "", [CallerLineNumber] int lineNumber = 0)
    {
        logger.LogInformation($"{message} ({filePath}:{lineNumber})");
    }
}

as a side note, I got an error saying that ILoggerFactory contains no definition for AddConsole. I found this answer 'ILoggerFactory' does not contain a definition for 'AddConsole'
So simply add the package like this:
dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console

You will also need the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging + Abstractions packages.
I also created a fiddle to show you how it works with the classical top level statements here https://dotnetfiddle.net/q680Vj
edit: I changed the implementation to an extension method of the ILoggerFactory which makes the method reusable across every instance of an ILogger instance. Also included using statements.

Is this a .csx (csharp script)? If so, I'd need the #r references. Would be nice if it ran here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ Otherwise, if it's normal csharp it's not going to work without a .csproj and neither is  dotnet add.

you can follow this guide and simply copy paste my code into the Program.cs
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates @Marc

See my added fiddle @Marc

I know but looked like Marc is new to C# so wanted to include a working example for him. Thank you anyway for your comment @phuzi

@Marc For future reference, unless explicitly stated otherwise it is fairly safe to assume that C# code in questions and answers would be part of a project/solution and not a csharp script (.csx)

@Aaron sorry, the comment was for OP.

Thanks phuzi, I'd never seen C# code outside of a class method except in scripts. Apparently a C# 10 feature called "top-level statements"!

To help clarify @Aaron's answer and provide an example which works on https://dotnetfiddle.net/:
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions;

namespace MyProject;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
        {
            builder.AddConsole(options =>
            {
                options.FormatterName = "lineLogger";
            }).AddConsoleFormatter<CustomFormatter, ConsoleFormatterOptions>();
        });
        var _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();
        _logger.LogWithLocation("Test Log");
    }
}

public class CustomFormatter : ConsoleFormatter
{
    public CustomFormatter() : base("lineLogger")
    {
    }

    public override void Write<TState>(in LogEntry<TState> logEntry, IExternalScopeProvider scopeProvider, TextWriter textWriter)
    {
        textWriter.WriteLine($"{logEntry.Formatter(logEntry.State, logEntry.Exception)}");
    }
}

public static class LoggerExtensions
{
    public static void LogWithLocation(this ILogger logger, string message, [CallerFilePath] string filePath = "", [CallerLineNumber] int lineNumber = 0)
    {
        logger.LogInformation($"{message} ({filePath}:{lineNumber})");
    }
}

Obviously on dotnetfiddle.net there are no filenames so the output is something like:
Test Log (:20)

But typically you would have the filename:
Test Log (C:\temp\Program.cs:20)

